# TFS Files checkout whenever build the solution

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I have VS 2010 in machine which is connected to TFS server. Now the problem is i have 10+ projects in my solution. whenever i try to build some of the projects would be checked out by itself. i tried many things but no luck , each time i have to undo checkout and then other people can work.

Comment: Are you building locally or are you using the tfs build services?

Comment: Local build. Abhishek's solution worked for me. but would like to know why such problem?

Comment: Are you sure that the check out happens when you build and not when you open the SLN? After the checkout, what Delta does the comparison of a checked out csproj show?

Comment: In both the cases. found the problem some of us use TFS server IP address and some of us use TFS Server Name. now all the members are changed there configuration to IP. and problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to Rebind project with TFS server and Re-Map it with your project folder. 
 then retry & Re-build.

Comment: Thanks, would like to know the reason behind as well.

Comment: Because version of Solution file not sync each other from source control and local project folder.